Permission denied (EACCES) on /opt/airflow/dags on Airflow Docker image from VS Code or the container itself
I'm developing on RHEL, and used podman to run the base airflow image (apache/airflow:latest) with the standalone argument. This is the command I used:
podman container run -d -p 8080:8080 -v /home/johnny/airflow/dags:/opt/airflow/dags apache/airflow:latest standalone

When attached to the container in VS Code, I cannot see any files in the /opt/airflow/dags folder, despite there being files present in /home/johnny/airflow/dags.
As a test, I tried creating a file in /opt/airflow/dags directly from VS Code, and this error appears:

Unable to write file 'vscode-remote://attached-container+7b22636f6e7461696e65724e616d65223a226e6572766f75735f7361746f736869227d/opt/airflow/dags/test.py' (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/opt/airflow/dags/test.py')

After exec-ing onto the container and navigating to the /opt/airflow/dags folder, I cannot even list the contents:
airflow@ac121943541f:/opt/airflow$ cd dags
ls


ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied

I tried changing the permissions of the directory, through the airflow user and root users, and getting permission denied in both cases. Here is the output of ls -l on /opt/airflow:
-rw-r--r--. 1 airflow root      3 Apr  6 21:33 airflow-webserver.pid
-rw-------. 1 airflow root  97299 Apr  6 21:33 airflow.cfg
-rw-r--r--. 1 airflow root 475136 Apr  6 22:34 airflow.db
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root    root     85 Apr  6 19:59 dags
drwxrwxr-x. 1 airflow root     52 Apr  6 21:33 logs
-rw-------. 1 airflow root     16 Apr  6 21:33 standalone_admin_password.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 airflow root   4761 Apr  6 21:33 webserver_config.py

Really stumped with this one, any direction appreciated.
Thanks.
